# jQuery mobile custom script working only on main mage in a multi-page layout

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a menu script in a seperate .js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#mmenu").hide();
$("#cover").hide();
var wys = $('#mmenu').height();
var open = false;
$(".mtoggle").click(function () {
    $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
    $("#cover").fadeToggle("400", "swing");
    if (open) {
        $(window).off('scroll.menuopen');
    } else {
        $(window).on('scroll.menuopen', scrollHandler);
        $(window).scrollTop(wys);
    }
    open = !open;
});
function scrollHandler(e) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > wys) {
        var limit = wys + 50;
        $(window).scrollTop(limit);
    }
}});
```

And a multi-page layout, where i determine new pages inside one html file like that:

```
<section data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a">, <section data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="a">, <section data-role="page" id="page3" data-theme="a">
```

The problem is that the menu-toggling script works only on the section #index, it doesn't affect the menu on other #pages. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: How is the menu on the other pages called? Do all of them have a #menu id? ID's need to be unique in the page

Comment: Yup, all of them have the same id - #mmenu. Should i create a seperate menu id and seperate script for every page? Is there a way to omit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id's need to be unique, while classes don't, so you could just use a class for that, like:

```
<div class="mmenu"></div>
```

and then use it in you js:

```
$(".mmenu").hide();
```

Comment: Oh right, that's kind of basic thing. Why didn't i think about it? :) Thanks